# Bootstrap tooltip on radio input

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, input, radio-button, tooltip

This code does not work. Also tried without JS, by putting attributes into `<input>`. Nothing seems to work.

```js
$('#radio1').tooltip({
    placement: "bottom",
    trigger: "hover"
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">

    <label class="btn btn-primary active">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="radio1" autocomplete="off" 
            data-toggle="tooltip" title="tooltip on radio!">Radio 1
    </label>

    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="radio2" autocomplete="off">Radio 2
    </label>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to apply tooltip's attributes to the `<label>`:

```js
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">

  <label class="btn btn-primary active" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="tooltip on radio!">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="radio1" autocomplete="off">Radio 1
  </label>

  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="radio2" autocomplete="off">Radio 2
  </label>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```